# iOS backward-compatible emoji support

Tags: android, ios, string, compatibility, emoji

During the implementation of a little cross-platform-chat we encountered problems with the displaying of emojis. Our minimum deployment target is iOS 9. Some emojis were introduced in later iOS versions. Those are displayed as a question mark box `[?]` on iOS 9.

On my research I just found Android questions and answers for that topic. On Android there is a text view `android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView` to support the displaying of emojis that are not available on the current system. There the emojis are replaced by similar available ones (e.g. with another skin color). [EmojiCompat Android Doku](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat.html)

Is there a framework, helper or system method available to do the same for iOS?

Comment: You can get font from newest iOS (macOS) version  and use him as custom font in old version iOS (macOS: font book app -> select font -> Show in Finder)